# hover pseudo-class not working on mat-icon element

Tags: css, angular-material, css-selectors

I have the following HTML markup:

```
<div class="recorder-ctrl-container" fxLayout="row"
    style="width:400px;height:70px;background-color: #22252B;border-radius: 3px;-webkit-app-region: drag;">

    <div fxFlex="30" style="display: flex;justify-content: center;align-items: center;">
        <div><mat-icon style="cursor: pointer;" matTooltip="Pause" matTooltipPosition="right">pause</mat-icon></div>
    </div>


</div>
```

and in the CSS file I have:

```
.recorder-ctrl-container mat-icon:hover{
    color: white;
}
```

With this in place, the hover is not working and `cursor:pointer` is not working too on the mat-icon element.

Comment: I would right click on mat-icon and inspect it to see how the object is being referenced with other CSS. I looked that up and see its Angular Material and in their example, their CSS references the mat-icon object by a class **.mat-icon** instead of the tag itself.

Comment: Yeah, I would guess that the `mat-icon` component is rendered as HTML elements rather than an actual web component.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by removing the property listed below from containing div tag.

```
-webkit-app-region: drag;
```